# I need all values in one list that "connect" to all values in another list

Tags: c#, sql, linq

```
"c"     "cft"
A        1,A
B        2,B
         3,A
         3,B
```

I need all values from the table "cft" where we have all items that exist in table "c". In the above example, only 3 has both A and B, and only 3 should be returned.

Is there a good way to implement this in LINQ (or MS-SQL)?

The only way I can figure out right now is to loop through all values of cft, but with a large table, that would be really inefficient.

Comment: is it linq2sql, linq2ef, or simply linq in managed code? do you have any classes for those tables? the technical term for "connect" is **join**.

Comment: I know what a join is, but I can't find a real way to join the tables in SQL to accomplish this. It's either Linq2Sql or just Linq to objects. I can pull the tables first if needed.

Comment: Could you possibly provide a more concrete dump of your tables, maybe even a SQL Fiddle, so that people can play around with? And could you possible provide a dump of the bewanted result, as the question is not that clear to me?

Comment: is cft a comma separatet string or are these proper fields? Some more information would be helpful.

Comment: @McLesevich, They are proper fields. Just comma separated above to be readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a LINQ query on the basis of your scenario below,

```
 from second in cft
 join first in c on second.cID equals first.ID

 group second by second.ID into gr
 where gr.Count() == c.Count
 select second.ID
```

Here table structure is something like ::

```
CREATE TABLE c (ID CHAR(1))
CREATE TABLE cft(ID INT, cID CHAR(1))
```

Comment: This seems like what I need! But with the 2nd last line from the end changed to something like:

`where gr.Count() == c.Count`

Comment: Yes i have also made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, assuming your tables are:

```sql
CREATE TABLE c (col CHAR(1))
CREATE TABLE cft(ID INT, col CHAR(1))
```

Then you can do this:

```sql
DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM c)

SELECT ID
FROM    (SELECT c.col, cft.ID
        FROM c
        JOIN cft ON c.col = cft.col) x
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = @Count
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty much what I wanted, except that the answer in LINQ was more directly usable for me, but does the same thing!

Comment: No problem, but I'm actually thinking that both answers are flawed.... more thinking required!

Comment: Is there a unique constraint (or primary key) on the `cft` table for those two columns?